# How to properly perform multiple redirection in C

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor, dup2, dup

I have a question regarding multiple redirections. As what I have for now writes in file1.txt only. I have to implement `echo hello > file1.txt > file2.txt > file3.txt` on my shell

Here is my code:

```
int fd1 = open(file1.txt, O_RDWR);
int fd2 = open(file2.txt, O_RDWR);
int fd3 = open(file3, O_RDWR);

dup2(fd1,1);    //to redirect fd1 on the stdout
dup2(fd2,fd1);  //to redirect fd2 to fd1 so i can read from fd1
dup2(fd3,fd1);  //to redirect fd3 to fd1 so i can read from fd1

char* arr = {"hello"};
execvp("echo",arr);
```

But the code above only works in the first redirection only. The rest which are fd2 and fd3 are not redirected as desired. Appreciate all the help! Thanks

EDIT: The expected results would be that for **file1.txt**, **file2.txt** and **file3.txt** would contain the word "hello".

Comment: What result do you expect from `echo hello > file1.txt > file2.txt > file3.txt`?

Comment: `for file1.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt would contain the word "hello".` - but there is only one `hello`, it can go to one file. `dup2` is meant to duplicate _the file descriptor_, not the data.

Comment: Just added the edit. But basically i expect that file1.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt all contain the word "hello". Thanks!

Comment: I want to be able to achieve what a normal terminal would do. correct me if i'm wrong but i think if you type this in normal terminal all files would contain "hello"

Comment: @PatrickInshutiMakuba Normally, a shell would create/truncate file1.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt but only write anything to file3.txt.  The other 2 files would be empty.

Comment: Yes, I made this assumption because i was debugging using macos with zsh. Otherwise, I really get it thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straight forward way to do this in classic Unix process model.

stdout can only point to one location, which is why `echo hello > file1.txt > file2.txt > file3.txt` will only write to `file3.txt` in most shells (bash, dash, ksh, busybox sh).

In these shells, you instead have to run:

```
echo hello | tee file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > /dev/null
```

Zsh is the only shell that would write to all three files, and it does it by implementing its own `tee` just like the above (by setting stdout to a pipe, and forking a process to read from the pipe and write to multiple files). You can do the same.

Comment: Yes, i just realized that I was testing on macos, which runs zsh. Thank you for the help!